# CMake set variable

Tags: cmake

In the following CMake code snippet, I am confused by the if elseif check. My understanding is that BL will always be "Ei", so there is no need to check other values. Are there any scenarios where BL could be overwritten by something else? I am new to CMake so need some help here.

```
set(BL "Ei" CACHE STRING "library")
set_property(CACHE BL PROPERTY STRINGS "Ei;AT;Op")
message(STATUS "The backend of choice:" ${BL})
if(BL STREQUAL "Ei")
...
elseif(BL STREQUAL "AT")
...
elseif(BL STREQUAL "Op")
...
else()
message(FATAL_ERROR "Unrecognized option:" ${BL})
endif()
```

Comment: You should try search for things setting "BL" That's probably a custom variable.

Answer (score 1):

The code `set(BL "Ei" CACHE STRING "library")` defines a CMake cache variable.  However, without a `FORCE` option in the `set` statement, that means that it will not be overwritten if the variable was previously defined in the cache.

One way for a user to set a different value for `BL` would be on the `cmake` command line.  For example: `cmake ../sourcedir -DBL:STRING=AT`

By entering the variable in the cache as type `STRING` (as opposed to type `INTERNAL`) that also makes the variable available to be configured in `cmake-gui` or in `ccmake`.  (Furthermore, the `set_property(... STRINGS ...)` directive tells `cmake-gui` to produce a drop-down list containing `Ei`, `AT`, and `Op` to select from.  However, this isn't enforced for setting the variable from the command line, which is why it's still a good idea to have the default case signalling an error.)

See the section "Set Cache Entry" under [CMake's documentation for `set`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html) for more information.